# Indian passport holder with less than 6 months before expiry travelling back to India

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, international-travel

I want to travel back to India from the US. Direct flight with Air India. But I have less than 6 months before expiry on my passport. My US visa is valid until 2025. I contacted the Air India helpline, but they said 6 months should be there.

When I contacted IAD airport they said the airline should decide according to the TIMATIC system. I'm an Indian passport holder going back to India. Do I really need at least 6 months?

Please can someone clear it because I can’t even get hold of the embassy?

Comment: Going back to your own country a valid passport should be enough, no extra time needed. And in many cases it can even be an expired passport. Are you sure the airline understood what you meant to say?

Comment: Yes I m sure, because I called them twice

Comment: Which office of the airline did you call?  Did you mention that you are an Indian citizen?

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to travel to India till the date of expiry of passport. You have to renew the passport in India before traveling back.

The information you got for 6 months is valid only for visiting other countries (Not all countries enforce this though).