Travel from India to USA with close passport expiry
i want to know if I will have any issues in the trip I'm planning.
My passport: India, I am Indian citizen with US Visa
Passport Expiry: 10 March 2025
US Visa Expiry: 6 April 2025
India to USA flight with layover in Qatar: 9 Sept
3 Domestic USA flights within America: 15th Sept, 25th Sept, 1st Oct
Return flight from USA to India with layover in Qatar: 7th Oct
I already know that my departure should be fine, as it's over 6mo to my passport expiry
But will there be a problem in:

Domestic US flights -- my passport will be less than 6mo expiry

Return flight with layover in Qatar -- even though I'm going back to my home country, I have a layover in Qatar with less than 6mo left in my passport.


I am really confused and unsure so would appreciate any help.

Just a note: is not easier to renew the passport? On some countries you can keep the old one until you get the new one (so good in case of delays). In any case ask to keep the old one (it will be cancelled, but some visa are still valid AND old passport have info that may be helpful to apply visas.

I think that's what I'll end up doing now @GiacomoCatenazzi, because I called Air India and they said my passport needs to expire at least 6months after the day I have returned back to India :/ same as https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/186076/indian-passport-holder-with-less-than-6-months-before-expiry-travelling-back-to i think

India is in the 6-month club, so the expiration date of your I-94 granted at entry will be no later than the expiration of your passport, which is fine since a 6-month admission will still end before your passport expiration. (On the other hand, if you were using a passport from a country not on the 6-month club, the expiration date of your I-94 can be no later than Sep 10, 2024, 6 months before the passport expiration, so you would only get a 1-day admission.)
For domestic flights in the US, any acceptable ID will work. How much validity is left doesn't matter.
I am not familiar with the passport requirements for transiting Qatar.

Thank you so much for the help! I can breathe a sigh of relief

For airside transit in Qatar, 6 month validity is not needed. The passport just have to be valid.
